# VB.NET Final line of textfile not being displayed

Tags: vb.net, file, text, file-io

I've built this game in vb.net windows forms called Go. Once the game finishes, it leads to a match breakdown screen. One of the features is a leaderboard. I have created a text file that stores the total number of points for each player in this so it can be displayed on the screen. I am updating the score after the game has finished by appending the new score to the textfile. If a player is new to the game, then a new record will be created. All records will be displayed in the leaderboard on the form.

The issue I am having is that when a new player plays the game, a new record is created. However, it is not being displayed on the leaderboard. I appreciate any advice you can give me, I am still a beginner at coding in VB. Here is an extract of the code below:

```
    filename = "F:\My Go project flood fill2\Text files\leaderboard.txt"
    files = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(filename, True) 'leaderboard
    files.Close()
    Dim leaderboardpath As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(filename)
    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)

    ...

    ElseIf leaderboardpath.Contains(handikomi(0, 0)) Then 'If one of the players has a record in text file
        For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
            newline = lines(i)
            'append line to new score for black
            Dim currentscore As String
            currentscore = newline.Split(New String() {","}, StringSplitOptions.None)(1).Split(",")(0)
            Dim tempscore As Decimal = currentscore
            currentscore = tempscore + btotalscore
            newline = newline.Split(New String() {","}, StringSplitOptions.None)(0).Split(",")(0) & ", " & currentscore & ", " & newline.Split(New String() {","}, StringSplitOptions.None)(2).Split(",")(0) & ", " & newline.Split(New String() {","}, StringSplitOptions.None)(3).Split(",")(0)
            lines(i) = newline
        Next
        IO.File.WriteAllLines(filename, lines)

        files = New StreamWriter(filename, True) 'leaderboard
        files.WriteLine(handikomi(1, 0) & ", " & wtotalscore & ", 0, 1") 'Writes new record to the file
        files.Close()

        ...

    EndIf

    ...

    leaderlbl.Text = "Leader Board"
    Dim leaderboard As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        leaderboard = leaderboard & " | " & lines(i)
        leaderlbl.Text = leaderlbl.Text & vbNewLine & lines(i).Split(New String() {","}, StringSplitOptions.None)(0).Split(",")(0) & "  " & lines(i).Split(New String() {","}, StringSplitOptions.None)(1).Split(",")(0)
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet you showed to write the leaderboard uses the `lines()` variable, but I don't see code updating the `lines()` variable after adding the score for a new player.  A quick and dirty way to solve this would be to re-read the file after you append a line to it.  Just change the snippet adding the new player score to something like this:

```
files = New StreamWriter(filename, True) 'leaderboard
files.WriteLine(handikomi(1, 0) & ", " & wtotalscore & ", 0, 1") 'Writes new record to the file
files.Close()
lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename) 'Update lines()
```